# Bad Twitter streaming request: 403

Tags: api, twitter, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to access twitter's api v1.1 filtered streaming endpoint but it gives me 403 error. I don't understand why. I can access other endpoints but not filtered stream for some reason.

It gives me this error-

HTTP ERROR: 403

Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json

Reason: Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a brand new developer account and app? v1.1 streams are deprecated and [new client apps cannot access `statuses/filter` as of the end of April 2022](https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecation-announcement-removing-compliance-messages-from-statuses-filter-and-retiring-statuses-sample-from-the-twitter-api-v1-1/170500), in preparation for future removal of the endpoint. The error message directs you to use the replacement v2 filtered stream API instead.

Comment: Yes this was a brand new developer account. Thanks for pointing this out, didn't notice until now.

Comment: @Andy Piper how can use V2 access in flume I am getting the same error when i try to access it with flume. please help me out with it. Do i need to add anything extra other than consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret token? in my conf file

Comment: You'll need to get a v2-capable Flume connector, or check with the Flume project on how the existing connector can work with Flume.