# Fetching twitter data using flumes 1.9.0

Tags: twitter4j, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

i am getting below error while trying to fetch the live tweets using flumes 1.9.0

```
*

content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 403 
    Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR: 403</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json'. Reason:
    <pre>    
    Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives
    </pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad Twitter streaming request: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130397/bad-twitter-streaming-request-403)

Comment: Actually I wanted to understand what exact changes I have to do in flumes configuration

Comment: None. The error comes from Twitter4j, not Flume. You could try replacing the Twitter4j JAR in the Flume classpath, but that is an OS filesystem change.