# Streaming Twitter Data with Flume - Twitter4J error

Tags: twitter4j, flume, flume-twitter

I am streaming twitter data using Flume and but getting an error regarding the twitter4j Jar File.

```
01:42:03.075 [Twitter Stream consumer /  [1][Establishing connection]] ERROR org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource - Exception while streaming tweets
twitter4j.TwitterException: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:185) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getSampleStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:201) ~[twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$4.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:170) ~[twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:570) ~[twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2048) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:2043) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:2042) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1609) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224) ~[?:?]
    at twitter4j.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:50) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:149) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1993) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308) ~[?:?]
    at twitter4j.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:35) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:149) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    ... 5 more
```

Here is my flume_project.conf

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.


# The configuration file needs to define the sources, 
# the channels and the sinks.
# Sources, channels and sinks are defined per agent, 
# in this case called 'TwitterAgent'

TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = kafkasink #filesink

#TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = AWS Marketplace, GCP Marketplace, Azure Marketplace

#filesink
# TwitterAgent.sinks.filesink.type = file_roll
# TwitterAgent.sinks.filesink.channel = MemChannel
# TwitterAgent.sinks.filesink.sink.directory = /docker_share/twitter_sink
# TwitterAgent.sinks.filesink.sink.pathManager.extension = out
# TwitterAgent.sinks.filesink.sink.pathManager.prefix = project
# TwitterAgent.sinks.filesink.sink.rollInterval = 3600

#kafkasink
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafkasink.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafkasink.topic = fp_mc
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafkasink.brokerList = fp_mc-kafka-1:9092
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafkasink.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.kafkasink.batchSize = 1
# add header and text to sink
# TwitterAgent.sinks.kafkasink.sink.serializer = header_and_text
# TwitterAgent.sinks.kafkasink.sink.serializer.appendNewline = true

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxx
```

I am using apache-flume-1.11.0

Everything is running in Docker

```
# 2. create topic using kafka container
docker exec -i fp_mc-kafka-1 kafka-topics.sh \
    --create \
    --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 \
    --replication-factor 2 \
    --partitions 2 \
    --topic fp_mc
```

including flume in a jdk container.
I use the following commands to start flume in the jdk container to collect the twitter data

```
docker exec -it fp_mc-jdk-1 bash

docker_share/apache-flume-1.11.0-bin/bin/flume-ng agent \
    -c /docker_share/conf \
    -f /docker_share/conf/flume_project.conf \
    -n TwitterAgent \
    -C /docker_share/apache-flume-1.11.0-bin/lib \
    -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

Twitter_project.yaml

```yaml
version: '3.5'

networks:
  twitter-demo:
    name: twitter-demo-net
    driver: bridge

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - twitter-demo

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    environment:
      # KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      # (Hack for Mac)use this if you want to have docker host node to be used as broadcast ip
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "/sbin/ip route|awk '/src/ { print $$NF }'"
      # Use below for Linux
      # HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $$7}'"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      # KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "varnish_raw_logs:10:1"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092
    networks:
      - twitter-demo
  
  #jdk container is used to run flume
  jdk:
    image: openjdk
    depends_on:
        - kafka
        - zookeeper
    volumes:
        - "./docker_share:/docker_share"
    command: 'tail -F anything'
    networks:
        - twitter-demo
  
#  elk container is used to run logstash, elasticsearch, and kibana
#  elk:
#    image: sebp/elk
#    volumes:
#      - "./docker_share:/docker_share"
#    depends_on:
#      - kafka
#      - zookeeper
#    ports:
#    - "5601:5601"
#    - "9200:9200"
#    - "5044:5044"
#    networks:
#      - twitter-demo

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=elastic

    image: elasticsearch:8.5.2
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - "./docker_share:/docker_share"
    networks:
      - twitter-demo

  logstash:
    image: logstash:8.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./docker_share:/docker_share"
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
    networks:
      - twitter-demo
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    links:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    image: kibana:8.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./docker_share:/docker_share"
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - twitter-demo
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    links:
      - elasticsearch
```

I am trying to stream twitter data using flume. I would expect to run the following command to stat kaka consumer message viewer and see tweets

```
docker exec -i fp_mc-kafka-2 kafka-console-consumer.sh \
    --bootstrap-server fp_mc-kafka-1:9092 \
    --topic fp_mc
```

Instead, I receive nothing due to the twitter4j error

Comment: I am having trouble with the twitter agent portion for flume. Fine to not use twitter4j if there is a better option. Could I do something with the flume_project.conf so I would not need to use twitter4j? I dont think this is necessary for streaming flume to HDFS

Comment: I don't think that API exists anymore. Try opening the url in your browser... If you're content with using Kafka, use Kafka Connect instead of Flume. Kafka Connect can also write to elastic, so you don't need logstash

Comment: Cricketeer you are awesome.... I am going to give that a try this afternoon. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Welcome. I'm removing the Kafka tag since your error is exclusive to Flume + Twitter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad Twitter streaming request: 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130397/bad-twitter-streaming-request-403)